# How to convert XML to Json with only STRING type

Tags: java, json, xml

I use JSONObject's `toJSONObject()` to convert XML into JSON. However, there is an annoying converting problem for me.

For example, my original XML looks like this:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><testData><Timestamp>20170907005718936</Timestamp><Detail><Item1>02907005718520</Item1><Item2>02907425118520</Item2><Item3>20170921133613</Item3></Detail></testData>
```

then I do the following to convert them into JSON:

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><testData><Timestamp>20170907005718936</Timestamp><Detail><Item1>02907005718520</Item1><Item2>02907425118520</Item2><Item3>20170921133613</Item3></Detail></testData>";
    try {
        JSONObject xmlObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml);
        System.out.println(xmlObj.toString());
    } catch (JSONException e) {
        // TODO Auto-generated catch block
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
```

After conversion, my data inside each tag is corrupted, because it thinks they are `NUMBERS`, not `STRING`.

```
{"testData":{"Timestamp":20170907005718936,"Detail":{"Item1":2907005718520,"Item2":2907425118520,"Item3":20170921133613}}}
```

How can I convert all tag values into String type only?

Comment: @CodeMatrix it's just "Converted", not into the data type I want

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can try convert every `number` to a `String`, something like:

```
String xml = "<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"UTF-8\" standalone=\"yes\"?><testData><Timestamp>20170907005718936</Timestamp><Detail><Item1>02907005718520</Item1><Item2>02907425118520</Item2><Item3>20170921133613</Item3></Detail></testData>";
xml = xml.replaceAll("(?<=\\d+)<", "\"<"); // any < preceded by digits
xml = xml.replaceAll(">(?=\\d+)", ">\""); // any > followed by digits
System.out.println(xml);
```

**Output:**

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?><testData><Timestamp>"20170907005718936"</Timestamp><Detail><Item1>"02907005718520"</Item1><Item2>"02907425118520"</Item2><Item3>"20170921133613"</Item3></Detail></testData>
```

**EDIT:**

If you may have `String` values that may start/end with a digit(s), you can specify the lower limit of how many digits your value should have to be considered as a `Number`, for example:

```
xml = xml.replaceAll("(?<=\\d{5})<", "\"<"); // any < preceded by at least 5 digits
xml = xml.replaceAll(">(?=\\d{5})", ">\""); // any > followed by at least 5 digits
```

Comment: this would add extra double-quote into my result if the value is STRING already. like `<Item4>Item4</Item4>`  would be turned into  `"Item4":"Item4\""` after XML 
 to JSON conversion. need to adjust it

Comment: But yours seem like most close to what I need. If there's no better one posted in next few days, I'll tag you as right answer.

Answer (score 3):

Try this,

> JSONObject xmlObj = XML.toJSONObject(xml,**true**);

the boolean after the input XML in a function will return as you expected the result.

thanks,
Morajse

Comment: sadly this solution come late, so I'll give you thumb up for useful

Answer (score 0):

I think this can be use :
Class :

```html
public JSONObject() {
    this.map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
}
 
 
public JSONObject(Map<String, Object> map) {
    this.map = new LinkedHashMap<String, Object>();
    if (map != null) {
        Iterator<Entry<String, Object>> i = map.entrySet().iterator();
        while (i.hasNext()) {
            Entry<String, Object> entry = i.next();
            Object value = entry.getValue();
            if (value != null) {
                this.map.put(entry.getKey(), wrap(value));
            }
        }
    }
}
```

Then on your main :

```html
String xml = FileUtils.readFileToString(new File("test.xml"));
System.out.println(org.json.XML.toJSONObject(xml).toString());
```

Hope it help's you ! =)

Comment: sadly this one make no different between using `XML.toJSONObject()`, my 0 on the left at each tag value still trimmed.